# How to use variables in alerts message while creating alert in Grafana(v 8.5.6) using Azure Monitor as a datasource?

Tags: grafana, azure-monitoring, grafana-variable, grafana-templating, grafana-alerts

I want to create an alert in Grafana (v 8.5.6)and I am using AzureMonitor as a datasource. While creating the alert I am not able to use Resourcegroup, Resource name or Metric Name in the message field of the alert. How to get these values populated using variables in the message field.

Anyhelp is highly appreciated.